# how can i use autopy to press a character on the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keypress, autoplay

"I want to press the 'C' key and the control button to copy something, but I don't know how to write it. I tried this code, 'autopy.key.toggle(autopy.key.Code.C, True),' and also this code, 'autopy.key.toggle(autopy.key.Code.CONTROL, True),' and I also tried the ASCII code of the character."

Answer (score 0):

i found this way in pyautogui insted of autopy:
import pyautogui

## Press 'V' key with the CONTROL modifier

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're on the right track, but the issue might be in the order of key presses and releases. You can use `autopy.key.toggle` for both key presses and releases. Here's an example code snippet to press the 'C' key along with the control button:

```
import autopy

**# Press and hold the control key**
autopy.key.toggle(autopy.key.Code.CONTROL, True)

**# Press the 'C' key**
autopy.key.toggle(autopy.key.Code.C, True)

**# Release the 'C' key**
autopy.key.toggle(autopy.key.Code.C, False)

**# Release the control key**
autopy.key.toggle(autopy.key.Code.CONTROL, False)
```

This code first presses and holds the control key, then presses the 'C' key, releases the 'C' key, and finally releases the control key. This should simulate the key combination for copying.

**Note:** The **`autopy.key.toggle`** function is used for holding keys, and the **`autopy.key.tap`** function is used for tapping a key without holding it.

Comment: this is the error "AttributeError: '_Code' object has no attribute 'C'"

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1